# Not able to get Rows values in asp:DataGrid ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have an asp datagrid like below

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgRegions" runat="server">
```

Now i want to access the column values of each row on "Submit" button click for which i tried using below code

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in dgRegions.Rows)
{
}
```

but Rows is not getting resolved and stating "Datagrid does not contain a definition of 'Rows'" What's wrong here?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, how to get the row values there. I updated like `foreach (GridViewRow r in dgRegions.Items)`

Comment: Are you using DataGrid or DataGridView control?

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya i am using `<asp:DataGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DataGrid you can get record collection in Items property.

```
  foreach (DataGridItem item in dataGrid.Items)
  { 
     //...
     var data = item.Cells[0].Text;

     //or
     CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("MyCheckBox");
     if (chkBox.Checked)
     {
         // do something
     }
  }
```

DataGridView has [Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) property and DataGrid has [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.items(v=vs.110).aspx) property for record collection.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to access the items inside loop?

Comment: Updated foreach for that. if you want to know more, "Items" is clickable and will take you to documentation page.

Comment: Thanks.If its 'Checkbox'  how to access its "Checked" "Uncked" status

Comment: I am sure you can find all information how to access data or controls on documentation page. Updated answer to show accessing the checkbox.